# Send one-way message to all threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, events, queue

I need to send information to every thread that's running in my program, and every thread has to process that information.

I can't do it using a regular queue, because that way once one thread removes the data from the queue all the other threads won't be able to see it anymore.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you know how many threads there are? Just set a static variable and have them all check that static variable but not modify it. If you don't know how many threads there are there's no way of knowing when all the threads have consumed the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to have a queue for *each* thread, and the function that broadcasts the information is responsible for inserting the message into the queue of every thread.

This is similar to the way message queues work in Windows, for example. Each thread that does GUI operations has an associated message queue, independent from that of any other thread.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought maybe such a type of queue already existed, but I'll try it this way then. Creating a queue for every thread and storing them in an array seems to work.