# Threads communication in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm a python beginner and I'm creating threads for a game. My server needs to send specific information for each player and public information for all of them. I have done the first with sockets, but I'm having problems with the public information. How can my server sends this information to all the threads (clients) involved when an event happens?
Thank you for any help you can bring me!

Comment: can you post the code which you tried which helps us to understand better

Comment: if you need to broadcast messages to your threads you may start from these two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521113/thread-synchronization-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531564/send-one-way-message-to-all-threads-in-python ; if you need to broadcast a message to all the players connected to your server we need more info as Mahesh Reddy Atla said.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the relation between threads and sockets? If you have a server and X clients connected to it then simply send the message to each client. Of course you have to keep a shared list of all connected clients. When a client connects add to that list and when he disconnects remove from that list. As simple as that.