# python how to serve multiple tcp clients with input from single udp port?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a python TCP server that listens for incoming data requests. As soon as someone connects to it, the server starts serving data to that client. The data it serves comes in via UDP on some port.

The question is, how can I serve the same data coming in from a UDP port to potentially multiple tcp clients?

Some background info: 
1. a thread is created to listen for incoming UDP data.
2. A new thread is created every time a new TCP clients connects.

I looked at the python Queue package, but it seems this is point-to-point and limiting for my objective.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want tee on a Queue. As far as I know it is not implemented. I am afraid of you are stuck with n queues, and have to supply the data to all of the Queues. Maybe you can wrap it in a class

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531564/send-one-way-message-to-all-threads-in-python

Comment: This fits into a publish-subscribe model  where the server is also a UDP client.  Suggest taking a look at ØMQ for this. Documentation is at http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out with Python server code at http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:wuserver and Python client code at http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:wuclient. The Pubsub module can also do this but I have not used it, see http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Interesting read on ØMQ. Thanks for both ideas. I'll try both

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the point-to-point connections in a class, for example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
from threading import Lock

class BroadcastChannel():
  def __init__(self):
    self._queues = []
    self.lock = Lock()
  def send(self, item):
    self.lock.acquire()
    for q in self._queues:
      q.put(item)
    self.lock.release()
  def fork(self):
    q = Queue()
    self.lock.acquire()
    self._queues.append(q)
    self.lock.release()
    return q
```